# Kops instance group in different accounts

Tags: kubernetes, kops

Is that possible to have IG in another account? We need to implement master multiaccount : 2 masters in 1 account and third master in second account. Is that possible from kops side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [kops terraform support](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/terraform/) in order to achieve that, but you'll have to perform some changes to the manifest.
Going down this path will probably remove a lot of the benefits for using kops, so there should be very good motives to implement such architecture.
Using kops alone will not allow this use case since it uses a single set of AWS credentials per cluster created.